# Can I travel from France to Croatia with a single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, tips-and-tricks, tourist-visas, croatia

If I'm in France, and have a single-entry Schengen visa, is it possible to go to Croatia and Montenegro?

I traveled between France, Austria, Italy without any problem. Is that so with other countries?

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked and answered before. No, you cannot travel to Croatia with a single-entry Schengen visa. You can only travel to Croatia with a double or multiple-entry Schengen visa. The same rules appply to Montenegro as well. Unfortunately the Ministry of Foreign and European Affairs in Croatia clearly states that you need a multiple-entry visa in order to do so.

In line with the Government’s decision, aliens who are holders of:

- a uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen Area member states;
- a visa with limited territorial validity (LTV visa), for two or multiple entries, issued to the holder of a travel document that is not recognised by one or more, but not all of the Schengen Area member states, and which is valid for the territory of the member states recognising the travel document;
- a long-stay visa (D) for stays exceeding three months, issued by one of the Schengen Area member state;
- a residence permit issued by one of the Schengen Area member state;

do not require a visa for transit through or intended stays in the territory of the Republic of Croatia not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period.